# "ERROR: please fill the required fields (name, email)." in WordPress?

Tags: html, wordpress, forms

I have a problem submitting a comment form for users who are not logged in. When I try to submit the forms, it is giving me an error:

> ERROR: please fill the required fields (name, email).

I am using the default template for WordPress. I have tried to deactivate the plugins one by one to make sure that this is not a conflict, but it is still not working. However, it's working fine for logged-in users.

Comment: Just to get this more visibility (see @Mohandes comments): if you have customized the comment form, be sure the `name=` of the fields is still correct, e.g. `name` and `email` and `url` respectively... it's fine if you have changed the `id=` attributes, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just make the email and name fields not required, To achieve this, go to `Dashboard > Settings > Discussion` and uncheck the  *Comment author must fill out name and email.*

[image: discussion settings]

**Edit:** 
*Read the comments for actual solution ...*

Comment: I am filling both email and name, then it should not show the error?

Comment: Can you please share the link of that page? or the custom codes if you have?

Comment: One thing that I noticed in your form:
The input field for the name has the attribute of `name="firstname"` I guess the codes check this by the attribute of `name="name"`.
Can you try changing it's name attribute from **firstname** to only **name**?

Comment: as well as the `id` attribute.

Comment: Sorry, change The name attribute to **author** (`name="author"`). This should work!
I just submitted a comment to your post right now

Comment: Where can I get that form, because I have searched comments.php and single.php, the form is not there. Could you please guide me

Comment: Where do I need to change exactly?

Comment: I don't know how you created the form, But you can try searching the form's class names globally in your project files to find the codes.
For instance, try searching in your project folder for text (comments-area), This might get you a hint to find the codes.

Comment: Once you find the form's html codes, change the `name` attribute of the input filed for *name*

Comment: Good, Happy to help you ;)

Comment: Hi @Mohandes, You can modify your answer so that I can accept your answer. I have made the correction and the form is working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Check the code below within your theme and remove 'comment-form' and 'comment-list'.

```
 add_theme_support(
            'html5',
            array(
                'search-form',
                //'comment-form',
                //'comment-list',
                'gallery',
                'caption',
            )
        );
```

Note this question should be on WordPress stackoverflow.